# Popular Tags module, show tags only from selected categories

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags, category-blog

I have a site with many articles, each articles has own tags, they are assigned to 3 main categories, lets say:

- Cat. "Blog Food": 15 articles with own tags
- Cat. "Blog Travel": 25 articles with own tags
- Cat. "Blog Hotel": 10 articles with own tags

I have 3 menu items with Blog view, each menu shows articles from one category, so I have 3 different blogs.

Now what I want to do is to show a "Popular tags" in each blog, showing tags only from this specific category.

The problem I have is that the module shows tags from all the articles, so tags from "food" blog are shown also in the "hotel" blog.

How can I make possible to show tags selecting the "source" of the tags, from example add a "popular tags" module on "food" blog that shows only tags taken from articles that are in "food" category.

I have tried to use the built in tags module and couple other additional module, but they show only all the tags from all the articles.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you develop your own module to do what you want. If I understand you right, you're saying that the Joomla `mod_tags_popular` does mostly what you want, apart from restricting the tags. So start with that module as the basis.

You'd be best to check the URL parameters (see [Requesting Data with JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)) to ensure that `option=com_content` and `view=category`, then your category id will be given by the `id` URL parameter.

Then you'll have to restrict the SQL query in the `mod_tags_popular` helper.php file by finding records from the `#__ucm_content` table where `core_catid` matches your `id`.

So after the lines:

```
$query->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__tags', 't') . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('tag_id') . ' = t.id')
        ->join('INNER', $db->qn('#__ucm_content', 'c') . ' ON ' . $db->qn('m.core_content_id') . ' = ' . $db->qn('c.core_content_id'));
```

put:

```
$query->where($db->qn('c.core_catid') . ' = ' . $id);
```

where `$id` contains the `id` URL parameter.